# If I go to '/contact', I want to preserve the previous routes view but show a modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So with the design for my website, there is no dedicated contact page. Instead, when clicking a /contact link, I need to show a modal. I could just do this in the traditional way but I want it so that:

a) If anyone lands directly on 'http://website.com/contact', it defaults to the homepage view and shows the modal automatically

b) If the visitor is already on the site and then activates the /contact route, it preserves the view they're currently on e.g. /about and then shows the modal on top of the /about view

Been trying to work this out in a new Vue 2 installation using Vue router but just can't work it out and i'm finding it very difficult to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following snippet, although I'm not entirely sure how to demo direct navigation to `/contact`.

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const contactGuard = function(to, from, next) {
  if (to.name === 'contact') {
    this.$root.$emit('modal', true)
    next(false)
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: {
      template: `<div><p>Home Page</p></div>`,
      beforeRouteLeave: contactGuard
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: {
      template: `<div><p>About Page</p></div>`,
      beforeRouteLeave: contactGuard
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    name: 'contact',
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (from.path) {
        // we're coming from another page
        this.$root.$emit('modal', true)
        next(false)
      } else {
        // we've directly navigated to /contact
        next({
          replace: true,
          path: '/',
          query: {
            contact: true
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  next(vm => {
    if (to.query.contact) {
      vm.$root.$emit('modal', true)
    }
  })
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      modal: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$on('modal', show => {
      this.modal = show
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modal-header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #42b983;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.modal-default-button {
  float: right;
}


/*
 * The following styles are auto-applied to elements with
 * transition="modal" when their visibility is toggled
 * by Vue.js.
 *
 * You can easily play with the modal transition by editing
 * these styles.
 */

.modal-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Foobar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{ name: 'home' }">Home</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{ name: 'about' }">About</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{ name: 'contact' }">Contact</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask" v-if="modal">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$root.$emit('modal', false)">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh! Okay I get the idea! Works nicely using jQuery to show the modal. Thanks for that :) Any idea how to make it show the modal as a .vue component instead? Obviously that way I can separate all the logic into the modal vue component and not have the code execute on every page, at least not until it's needed

Comment: Do you know how i'd be able to access query.contact inside of the main App.vue? I'm thinking of calling the component "<contact></contact>" with v-if="query.contact" @DigitalDrifter

Comment: @JonathanPort Should be easy enough to swap out the bootstrap modal for something like [this example](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html).

Comment: You can access the current route query parameters via `$route.query`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, apologies for the silly questions. I'm very new to Vue. Hard to get my head around coming from a PHP / Laravel background @DigitalDrifter

Comment: Happy to help, Laravel and Vue are both great frameworks!

Comment: @JonathanPort I've updated the answer to use the example modal I linked above.

Comment: Yeah love laravel! and Ahh actually just noticed that although it does work as intended, the url is changed. Any way to preserve the /contact?

Comment: You can omit the `{ replace: true }` option to preserve the url.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to offer another way of doing it. The differences are that it preserves routes (doesn't change to query), and doesn't rely on jQuery.

The way it works is that it (also) relies on beforeEnter to adjust the route information.

Instead of using the default way of defining the component in the routes, I put it into the meta. This makes it easy to copy from `from` into the `to`

The `/contact` route uses a `showContact` meta to determine whether to show the overlay

example:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', meta: { component: Home } },
  { path: '/bar', meta: { component: Bar } },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    meta: { showContact: Contact, component: null },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (from.matched[0]) {
        to.meta.component = from.matched[0].components.default;
      }
      next();
    },
  },
];
```

The last bit is that the instead of using `<router-view/>`, I use `<component v-bind:is="$route.meta.component"></component>` to display the component

And to show the contact form: `<component v-if="$route.meta.showContact" v-bind:is="$route.meta.showContact"></component>` or `

Here is a condesandbox example, without any styling:

[image: Edit Vue Template]